# Publishing/Deploying with Helix Publishing Pipeline

Tags: helix, deployment, module

I need to implement a publishing step in a TFS Build deployment process to generate the Build artifacts. We are using Gulp for our local build/publishing process, but want to try and use HPP for TFS builds.

So first I tried to add the https://github.com/richardszalay/helix-publishing-pipeline Nuget package to my Helix website Project.

I edited the csproj of website and added the below . I also created a new website Publishing. Project and added the same and got the below error:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Foundation\*\code\*.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Feature\*\code\*.csproj" />   
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Project\*\code\*.csproj" /> 
  </ItemGroup>



<DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
  <PublishProfile>Company-DEV</PublishProfile>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- The rest can go into ProjectName.wpp.targets if you prefer -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoPublish Condition="'$(AutoPublish)' == '' and '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' and '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' and '$(PublishProfile)' != ''">true</AutoPublish>

  <AutoPublishDependsOn Condition="'$(AutoPublish)' == 'true'">
    $(AutoPublishDependsOn);
    WebPublish
  </AutoPublishDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But I am getting this error -

> There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "CollectReferencesFromHelixModules".

If I remove this line - `<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Project\*\code\*.csproj" />` then the error goes away.

Can anyone help to figure out why the circular dependency can be removed. I also want the Project website, bin to be generated in the build artifacts.

Comment: Did you add the HPP website project to the the `Project` folder?

Comment: Yes @RichardSeal I added to Project first and then got this error , then i created a new Publishing Project , and got the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you have added the HPP Website project to your Helix `Projects` folder, and so its trying to add a reference to itself and getting into a Circular reference.

When I use HPP I set my folders up like this:

```
Solution
-- Feature
-- Foundation
-- Project
-- Website
   -- HelixPublishingPipeline.Website.csproj
```

Doing it like that should clear up any circular references.

Comment: Let me try moving the publishing Project outside "Project" folder and into a  website folder

Comment: Thanks , it works on moving project with HPP to its own website folder. Would this structure be in-line with Helix principles ?

Comment: yeah.  I solved that issue by moving the HPP publishing project outside of the dynamic Project layer structure.  Helix principles do not dictate a physical structure, but a rather a set of guidelines between physical or logic boundary which do not depend on filesystem.  That's an implementation details imho.